# Make first letter in UiTextField lowercase (Phonegap for iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, uitextfield, lowercase

When I type the letter in username field, the first letter always a capital. How can I make the first letter in `UITextField` lowercase. I don't know how to fix this in Phonegap.

```
<form id="loginForm">
<div   class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  value="" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Phonegap, but with a normal UITextfield you can use this line (where textField is the outlet for a UITextField):

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Answer (score 15):

I faced similar issue during my iOS development. I used

```
<input ..... autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: Simple and awesome for Cordova based apps :-)

Answer (score 3):

This might not the best way though, I use this:

```
<input type="email" name="username" id="username" />
```

just change `input type` from `text` to `email`

Answer (score 0):

I've used a css property text-transform:lowercase; 
If you're using phonegap that works!